# One-One object not being linked to Existing Object

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Not being able to post a one one related object with resource uri :

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/job/
```

```
{ "name":"jobstestfinal2",
  "payment":"/api/v1/payment/2/"
}
```

getting no error . just null in place of payment object.

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Payment(models.Model):
    scheduled = models.DateTimeField()
    job = models.OneToOneField(
        Job,
        related_name="payment",
        blank=True,
        null=True)
```

resource.py

```
  class PaymentResource(ModelResource):
        job = fields.ToOneField(
            'myapp.resources.JobResource',
            'job', null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            queryset = Payment.objects.all()
            resource_name = 'payment'
            authorization = Authorization()
            allowed_methods = ('get', 'put', 'post')


class JobResource(ModelResource):
    payment = fields.ToOneField(
        PaymentResource,
        'payment',
        related_name='job',
        null=True, blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        queryset = Job.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'job'
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ('get', 'put', 'post')
```

FYI following end points are working fine :
GET job , payment
POST job [ with payment object ]
     payment [ with job uri ]
     payment [ with job object ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the example post url that you posted.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/job/ 

{ "name":"jobstestfinal2",
  "payment":"/api/v1/payment/2/" # Not sure if you have to use payment_set or not.
}
```

change your `foreign key` from `Payment` to `Job`

```
class Job(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  payment = models.ForeignKey( # Changed from OneToOne to ForeingKey
    Payment,
    blank=True, # True means a job doesn't have to have a payment
    null=True # Allowing the value NULL in your database
  )

class Payment(models.Model):
  scheduled = models.DateTimeField()
```

You can add Payment to a Job

```
job = Job(name='nice job')
job.save() # Your Job must have an ID before you can link it to a Payment
payment = Payment(scheduled='2014-1-1 10:00')
job.payment_set.add(payment)
job.save()
```

and a Job to a Payment.

```
job = Job(name='nice job')
job.save() # Your Job must have an ID before you can link it to a Payment
payment = Payment(scheduled='2014-1-1 10:00')
payment.job = job # The difference is the _set.add when you do it through the Job model
payment.save()
```

Comment: my question is specific to how to do this via an api post request . solution you gave is for shell i think

Comment: Please take a closer look at my example. I create a reference from Payment to Job. What you are trying to do is from Job to Payment. If I do `curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"scheduled": "2013-10-10 00:00", "payment": "/api/v1/job/2/"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/payment/` I get what you are trying

Comment: sorry not getting you . do i need to make a hydrate/dehydrate function and add some manipulation ? and the request you explained in example is already working .

Comment: I understand your answer now but i want to make it work both ways . ie. job [with payment uri] and payment [ with job uri ] i already have it working from either side .<pre>
what i did    : job ---> payment.
what you said : payment --> job .
what i want   : job <----> payment .</pre>

Comment: I'll check if making one-one key from both side's will make it work .